# PHP array sort / multi_sort usort

Tags: php

I need to sort this array by distance

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pyro Pizza
            [distance] => 2.3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sparky's Pizza
            [distance] => 2.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => American Dream Pizza - Portland
            [distance] => 0.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ken's Artisan Pizza
            [distance] => 1.1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sparky's Pizza - SE
            [distance] => 2.2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vincente's Gourmet Pizza and the V-Room
            [distance] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Blind Onion Pizza and Pub
            [distance] => 0.6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hot Lips Pizza
            [distance] => 1.9
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Flying Pie Pizzeria
            [distance] => 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hammy's Pizza
            [distance] => 2.4
        )

)
```

I used this..

```
usort($results, 'sortByOrder');
```

with this..

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['distance'] - $b['distance'];
}
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    if ( $a ['distance'] == $b ['distance'] ) return 0;
    return ( $a ['distance'] < $b ['distance'] ) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort ( $results, 'sortByOrder' );
```

The problem with your code is that the comparison function, sortByOrder here, should return either 0 if they are equal or -1/1 if one of them is bigger. Your function however returned the difference in distance, which usort() can't parse.

Answer (score 3):

Your sortByOrder function doesn't look quite right.

From [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

> The comparison function must return an
>   integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first
>   argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or
>   greater than the second.

Comment: @Kirk Strobec "Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today.  Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime"

Comment: Concepts and syntax are two different worlds — In your analogy what you did is said "go get fish" as opposed to "go to the north shore with X net and Y boat at Z hour with A bait"

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck "Thanks man but I cannot figure out the function description or the several examples given on php.net - I would appreciate if you could expand some more. Cheers!"

Comment: I dont understand it either, thats why I posted the question, see the answer to learn more ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
    function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
        if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0; 
        return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```